# What's the excact effect of not specifying the `-t` in `-it`?

Tags: docker

The [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) claims:

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often written -it as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying -t is forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe, as in:

So, what happens if I omit the `-t` flag? Is there a reasonable scenario for just providing the `--interactive` flag without the `-t` flag?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Most containers shouldn't need either.  There's a specific bug in some versions of `react-scripts` that requires `-i`, but not `-t`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. im_baby, how can I try something I don't see a reason for?

Comment: This is particularly true on Windows.